# getChildcount for specific Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, android-framelayout

I've got a framelayout with one static Imageview where randomly other Imageviews are placed.
I want to use "getChildCount" to get the number of those randomly placed ImageViews, but it also refers to the static one. How can I solve that?

Comment: do `getChildCount() - 1`? or am I missing something?

Comment: actually I want to move those images and so I write: ImageView image  = (ImageView) layout.getChildAt(nummer)

Comment: you could give the static ImageView an id and then just check all children and only move them when they are not the given id

Answer (score 0):

You should call getChildCount only when the new ImageView was added and drawn on the layout.Try using:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getChildCount()

            }
        })
```